# Prior Year to Date Window Function for Trino (PrestoSQL)

Tags: amazon-emr, presto, trino

I was trying to figure out how to get a sum and avg of a metric for the time period "prior year to date" using only a single window function, as I have many window functions and wanted to keep my code as simple as possible. I don't know if anyone else will find this useful, but showing my own solution here in case it is helpful.

Last year to date, prior ytd, last ytd etc. (different terms companies use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```sql
SELECT
    sum(metric) OVER prior_year_to_date,
    avg(metric) OVER prior_year_to_date
FROM orders
WINDOW prior_year_to_date AS (
    ORDER by your_date
    RANGE BETWEEN 
        your_date - date_trunc('year', your_date - interval '1' year) PRECEDING AND 
        interval '1' year PRECEDING
)
```

Some observations:

- You can use the [`WINDOW`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#window-clause) clause to define the window once and reuse it across many functions.
- The `RANGE` window frame can operate directly on datetime types. In this case, the range is defined as the interval that starts N days before `your_date` for the current row (where N is the number of days required to offset that date to the beginning of the previous year) and 1 year before the `your_date` for the current row.

You can found more details about the usage of `WINDOW` and `RANGE` in Trino [here](https://trino.io/blog/2021/03/10/introducing-new-window-features.html).

Comment: This is way simpler, thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running PrestoSQL (Trino) version 350.0 on EMR. This is only possible with versions 346 and later I think. This will not work with PrestoDB at time of writing.

```html
select
    avg(your_metric) 
        over (
            partition by your_partition_columns
            order by (to_unixtime(your_date)/86400) 
            range between 
                ((to_unixtime(your_date)/86400)  - (to_unixtime(last_day_of_month(date_trunc('year',date_add('year',-1,your_date))))/86400))
                preceding 
                and 
                ((to_unixtime(your_date)/86400) - (to_unixtime(last_day_of_month(date_add('year',-1,your_date)))/86400)) 
                preceding
        ) 
        as your_metric_avg_prior_year_to_date
from your_table
```

Comment: You don't need to divide the unixtimes by 86400 (this converts them to days) it just made it easier for me to inspect while building.

Comment: Here's the simplified version:
select
    avg(your_metric) 
     over (
      partition by your_partition_columns
      order by to_unixtime(your_date)
      range between 
       (to_unixtime(your_date)  - to_unixtime(last_day_of_month(date_trunc('year',date_add('year',-1,your_date)))))
       preceding 
       and 
       (to_unixtime(your_date) - to_unixtime(last_day_of_month(date_add('year',-1,your_date)))) 
       preceding
     ) 
     as your_metric_avg_prior_year_to_date
from your_table